# Take numbers from input and plug into an equation javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, input, numbers, user-defined-functions

I need help figuring out how to make this work if anyone can give me some insight as soon as possible even a little help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

```
<body>
<form name="kdr">   
Kills:  <input type="number" id="kill" name="kill"></input>
<br>
Deaths: <input type="number" id="death" name="death"> </input>
<br>
<button onclick="kd()"> Calculate</button>
</form>


<script>

        function kd()
        {
        var k = document.getElementById("kill").value;
        var d = document.getElementByID("death").value;
        var r = k/d
        alert("Your kill/death ratio is: " + r)
        }


</script>   
</body>
```

I cant seem to get the variables to pull the information from the input field, at least I think that is the issue. Again any insight would be great.

Comment: getElementByID should be getElementById

Answer (score 0):

You have `ID` in your `d` assignment when it should be `Id` like in your `k` assignment.

Comment: Parsing isn't required, but there's no check for divide by zero errors :)

Comment: aaah I didn't notice he already had `type='number'` in the elements!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Xaleph/k3Hv9/

Looks like Sam beat me to it.  ID should be id and I added semicolons to the end just for good measure.

Also - consider not using inline javascript events.  Instead, put your code in a supporting file and handling events similar to the following will make your code a little easier to manage (from w3schools - can't add another link, not enough reputation...).

```
object.onclick=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};
```

Or if you're feeling adventurous, use [jquery](http://jquery.com/) or another javascript library to handle your events:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
    alert("Your kill/death ratio is: " + ($('#kill').val()/$('#death').val()));
}
```